# Tomcat 8.5 not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, tomcat8.5

I installed apache tomcat 8.5 but it didn't show up while creating dynamic web project in Eclipse Indigo. It showed up versions until 7.0 only. Finally, I had to install tomcat 7 to proceed. What could be the issue?

Comment: Why don't you get upgraded to latest eclipse which in turn will update the `WTP tools`?

Comment: What is your eclipse version ?

Comment: Use Eclipse Neon and you will get Tomcat 8.5

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Eclipse Neon which supports Tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Install "JST Server Adapters Extensions (Apache Tomcat)" (via window menu > "Help" > "Install New Software"):
[image: JST Server Adapters in Eclipse]